# Primefaces datatable headers duplicated when adding a new row

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am getting a strange behaviour using primefaces' dataTable.
When I add a new row to the list and the dataTable refreshes, headers get duplicated; so, after first row is added, headers are displayed 2 times, after second row 4 times, and so on.
I tried to remove filtering options but I still get the same behaviour.
Someone experienced the same problem?
I am using Primefaces 4.0 with Tomcat 7.

Thanks in advance at anyone who can help me and sorry for my poor english.

Here is an image that shows the behaviour:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysm6y.png

---

This is my code: an index.xhtml page includes my movementList.xhtml page containing the dataTable:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<h:head>
    <link href="/#{COREWEB_MODULE_URL}/css/jsf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</h:head>

<ui:include src="/jsp/faces/common/varImages.xhtml"/>

<h:body style="background-color:grey;">

<p:growl id="messages"/>

<p:dock position="top" halign="center" >
    <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{imgHome64}" url="index.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Movimenti" icon="#{imgNoteBook64}" url="/movement/list.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Mutuo" icon="#{imgEuro64}" url="/bankLoan/list.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Grafici" icon="#{imgChart64}" url="/graph/list.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Dizionario" icon="#{imgBook64}" url="/dictionary/list.xhtml"/>
</p:dock>

<p:stack icon="/images/stack/stack.png">
    <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="#{imgHome64}" url="index.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Movimenti" icon="#{imgNoteBook64}" url="/movement/list.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Mutuo" icon="#{imgEuro64}" url="/bankLoan/list.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Grafici" icon="#{imgChart64}" url="/graph/list.xhtml"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Dizionario" icon="#{imgBook64}" url="/dictionary/list.xhtml"/>
</p:stack>

<div style="display:block;width:1300px;height:50px;">
    <div style="float:left;width:1120px;" id="menuTopDiv">

    </div>
    <div style="float:left;width:180px;height:50px;" id="themeSwitcherDiv">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
            <p:themeSwitcher value="#{guestPreferences.theme}" style="width:165px" effect="fade" id="statefulSwitcher">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose Theme" itemValue="" />  
                <f:selectItems value="#{themeSwitcherBean.themes}" />  
                <p:ajax listener="#{themeSwitcherBean.saveTheme}" />  
            </p:themeSwitcher>  
        </h:panelGrid> 
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:block;width:1300px;height:220px;">
    <div id="menuTopLeftDiv" style="float:left;width:300px;height:220px;">
        <ui:include src="/jsp/faces/menu/menuLeft.xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <div id="latestIncomeDiv" style="float:left;width:490px;height:220px;margin-left:0.3em;">
        <ui:include src="/jsp/faces/latestIncomeWidget.xhtml"/>
    </div>
    <div id="latestOutcomeDiv" style="float:left;width:496px;height:220px;margin-left:0.3em;">
        <ui:include src="/jsp/faces/latestOutcomeWidget.xhtml"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="float:left;display:block;width:1300px;">
    <ui:include src="/jsp/faces/movement/movementList.xhtml"/>
</div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

movementList.xhtml

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="movementForm">
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

<p:accordionPanel id="movementAccordion">
    <p:tab title="Elenco Movimenti">

        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="movement" value="#{movementJsf.movementList}" widgetVar="movementTable"
            emptyMessage="No movements found with given criteria"
            paginator="true" rows="10" editable="true" stickyHeader="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

            <p:column style="padding:0.2em;width:2.5em;text-align:center;" filterBy="#{movement.direction.name}"
                headerText="Dir" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:graphicImage url="#{movement.directionId == 3 ? imgArrowUpGreen16 : imgArrowDownRed16}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="padding:0.2em;" filterBy="#{movement.direction.name}" 
                headerText="Direzione" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{movement.direction.name}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="padding:0.2em;" filterBy="#{movement.type.name}"
                headerText="Movimento" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{movement.type.name}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="padding:0.2em;width:6em;text-align:right;" headerText="Data">
                <h:outputText value="#{movement.operationDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="padding:0.2em;width:6em;text-align:right;" headerText="Ammontare">
                <h:outputText value="#{movement.amount}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="de-DE"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Azioni" style="padding:0.2em;width:6em;text-align:right;">
                <h:graphicImage url="#{imgPageEdit}" title="Modifica" alt="Modifica" id="movement_edit_#{movement.id}"/>
                <h:graphicImage url="#{imgPageDelete}" title="Cancella" alt="Cancella" id="movement_remove_#{movement.id}"/>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>

<p:commandButton id="modalDialogButton" value="Aggiungi movimento" onclick="PF('movementFormDialog').show();" type="button"/>

<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="movementFormDialog" modal="true" height="400" resizable="false"
    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:ajax event="close" update="messages" immediate="true" global="false"
        listener="#{movementJsf.addMovement}"/>

    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Aggiungi movimento
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputLabel for="type" value="Tipologia: *"/>
        <p:autoComplete value="#{movementJsf.typeId}" id="movementType" completeMethod="#{facesService.movementTypeAutocomplete}"
            var="type" itemLabel="#{type.name}" itemValue="#{type.id}" forceSelection="true"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="amount" value="Ammontare *"/>
        <h:inputText size="20" value="#{movementJsf.amount}"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="operationDate" value="Data operazione: *"/>
        <p:calendar value="#{movementJsf.operationDate}" id="operationDateCalendar" locale="it" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" effect="slideDown"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="estimated" value="Stimato: *"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{movementJsf.estimatedId}" effect="fade">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleziona" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{facesService.movementEstimatedList}" var="dictionary" itemLabel="#{dictionary.name}" itemValue="#{dictionary.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton id="addFormButton" value="Aggiungi" action="#{movementJsf.addMovement}"
            oncomplete="PF('movementFormDialog').hide();" update="movementForm:movementAccordion:dataTable"/>
        <p:commandButton id="undoFormButton" value="Annulla" onclick="PF('movementFormDialog').hide();" type="button"/>
</p:dialog>

</h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

MovementJsf.java

```
package it.fronte.account.jsf;

import it.fronte.account.command.search.MovementSearchCommand;
import it.fronte.account.model.Movement;
import it.fronte.account.service.AccountService;
import it.fronte.dictionary.model.Dictionary;
import it.fronte.dictionary.service.DictionaryService;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils;

@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "movementJsf")
public class MovementJsf {

    protected AccountService accountService = (AccountService) FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBean("accountService");
    protected DictionaryService dictionaryService = (DictionaryService) FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBean("dictionaryService");

    // Properties

    public BigDecimal amount;
    public Integer estimatedId;
    public Date operationDate = new Date();
    public Integer typeId;

    public List<Movement> movementList = new ArrayList<Movement>();

    public List<Movement> getMovementList() {
        MovementSearchCommand searchCommand = new MovementSearchCommand();
        searchCommand.setAccountId(1);
        searchCommand.setSort("operationDate");
        searchCommand.setSortDirection("desc");
        searchCommand.setPage(1);
        searchCommand.setPageSize(99999999);
        this.movementList = accountService.searchMovement(searchCommand);
        return movementList;
    }

    // Getters & Setters

    public Integer getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(Integer typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Integer getEstimatedId() {
        return estimatedId;
    }

    public void setEstimatedId(Integer estimatedId) {
        this.estimatedId = estimatedId;
    }

    public Date getOperationDate() {
        return operationDate;
    }

    public void setOperationDate(Date operationDate) {
        this.operationDate = operationDate;
    }

    // Constructors

    public MovementJsf() {

    }

    public MovementJsf(Integer typeId, BigDecimal amount, Date operationDate, Integer estimatedId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.operationDate = operationDate;
        this.estimatedId = estimatedId;
    }

    // CRUD methods

    public String addMovement() {
        Movement movement = new Movement();
        movement.setAccountId(1);
        movement.setCreationDate(new Date());
        movement.setLastModifiedDate(new Date());
        movement.setTypeId(this.typeId);
        Dictionary type = dictionaryService.getDictionary(this.typeId);
        movement.setDirectionId(getDirection(type));
        movement.setAmount(this.amount);
        movement.setEstimatedId(this.estimatedId);
        movement.setOperationDate(this.operationDate);
        accountService.saveOrUpdate(movement);

        movementList.add(0, movement);

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Movimento aggiunto", "Movimento aggiunto");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        return null;
    }

    private Integer getDirection(Dictionary dictionary) {
        if (dictionary.getParentDictionaryId() != null)
            return getDirection(dictionary.getParentDictionary());
        else
            return dictionary.getId();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to downgrade my jar file from PrimeFaces 4 to PrimeFaces 3.5 and now all works well.
Maybe it is a bug in version 4.0

Comment: Report it to PrimeFaces guys then so that they can fix it.

Comment: The problem was related to the use of the "stickyHeader" attribute in p:dataTable, it is not supported in Primefaces 4; so removing it the behaviour disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

to solve remove the scrollable="true" or change to scrollable="false"

Comment: Why? What version? Latest version to? Please be way more specific

Comment: I see this bug in primefaces 5.2. Don't know if was fixed in last version: 5.2.13. Don't know why. Someone more can make more tests